# Remove XAML Designer error for resources created at runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10

I have some shared resources in my app (let's say it's a simple `SolidColorBrush` object) that I use in different controls and elements.

If my resources are initialized in a shared resource dictionary, I can reference them in my XAML code with `{StaticResource MyResourceName}` just fine and everything works fine.

The issue is that I have some resources that depend on some runtime properties (the type of device, for example), so I initialize them in C# when the app starts.

Then of course, the XAML Designer can't find those resources, as they've not yet been created, underlines those lines and signals an error.

[image]

> **Is there a way to hide these XAML Designer errors** in case I'm
>   referencing a resource I know will be available at runtime?

---

**EDIT**: here's an example for how I'm loading the resources at runtime:

```
SolidColorBrush test = new SolidColorBrush { Color = Colors.Green };
Application.Current.Resources["MyRuntimeResource"] = test;
```

Comment: how will you make the resource available  at runtime?

Comment: your sample is bad, if i were you, i prefer directly set `Border.Background` in code behind. why use resource?

Comment: You can try using design time resources. But you will still need to create them, just don't have to use them when the app is running

Comment: @LeiYang "Why use resource?" - seriously? Do you really think it'd be a better practice to just go ahead and manually initialize that background in code behind in every single control where I'm using that resource?

Comment: have you heard of dynamic resource?

Comment: @LeiYang DynamicResource isn't supported in a UWP application, so I can't actually try it out. I'm just looking for a way to hide the warnings in the XAML designer, nothing more

Comment: i didn't know DynamicResource wasn't available

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ThemeResource
    `<Border Background="{ThemeResource MyRuntimeResource}"/>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources

> Evaluation of a {ThemeResource} markup extension occurs when the app loads

Comment: Using a `ThemeResource` gives the same warning, as the resource isn't even declared at that point in the XAML Designer, so it can't find it. The reason for this is that the resource (say, a `Brush`) can be initialized with different classes (for example, I could use both a custom composition brush and a `SolidColorBrush`), so I can't declare it in advance in XAML, as I don't know what type will it actually have at runtime.

Comment: You can also declare a default value for the resource in your Application.Resources 
 `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="color" Color="Blue" />`
and change it's value on the application startup
`Application.Current.Resources["color"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`
this way the designer will find the StaticResource and it's value will change on runtime.

Comment: if StaticResource can be changed then why uwp omits DynamicResource as the OP said?

Comment: @LeiYang A StaticResource can be changed as in "you can initialize it to a different value at runtime", but those changes won't be reflected in the UI. In fact, you have to initialize those resources before loading the UI because of this.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted a way to hide the warnings without having to create "fake" unnecessary resources at startup. I mean, I'd prefer not to use actual CPU time and memory at runtime to initialize those default resources just to solve that problem with the designer.